# scrolling to bottom of element has some gap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I want to scroll to the bottom of my chatbox element whenever I had a new message but the scroll goes just before the last message not to the last message.
[image: GIF_description]

I used scrollIntoView and element.scrollHeight but both of them have a gap and the last message is not appearing on the screen, I need to scroll more to see the last message.

index.tsx

```
import { KeyboardEvent, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import femaleUserPhoto from "../../../public/assets/images/female_user.png";
import styles from "./style.module.scss";

const fakeMessages = [
  { id: 1, name: "sara", text: "سلام" },
  { id: 2, name: "ayda", text: "خوبین؟" },
  { id: 3, name: "hosna", text: "ما خوبیم تو چطوری؟" },
];

const Chatbox = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState(fakeMessages);
  const [chatBoxMessage, setChatBoxMessage] = useState("");

  const messagesRef = useRef(null);
  const endOfMessagesRef = useRef(null);

  const handleKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (event.code == "Enter") {
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [
        ...prevMessages,
        { id: Math.random() * 10000, name: "saba", text: chatBoxMessage },
      ]);
      setChatBoxMessage("");

      // messagesRef.current.scrollTop = messagesRef.current.scrollHeight;

      endOfMessagesRef.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "end",
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.chatbox}>
      <input
        className={styles.chatbox__input}
        type="text"
        placeholder="پیام شما ..."
        value={chatBoxMessage}
        onChange={(event) => setChatBoxMessage(event.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      />
      <div ref={messagesRef} className={styles.chatbox__messages}>
        {messages.map((message) => {
          return (
            <div key={message.id} className={styles.chatbox__messages__message}>
              <Image
                src={femaleUserPhoto}
                alt="female_user_photo"
                width={60}
                height={60}
              />
              <div className={styles.chatbox__messages__message__detail}>
                <span>{message.name}</span>
                <span>{message.text}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <div
          className={styles.chatbox__messages__end}
          ref={endOfMessagesRef}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chatbox;
```

style.module.scss

```
.chatbox {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: $secondary-color;

    &__input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 16px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid $gray;
        background-color: $secondary-color;
        color: $gray;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: $shabnamBoldFont;
    }

    &__messages {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: calc(100% - 55px);

        &__end {
            height: 1px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }

        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        scrollbar-width: none;

        &__message {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            align-items: stretch;
            column-gap: 8px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid $gray;
            padding: 16px 0;

            &:last-child {
                border-bottom: 0;
            }


            &__detail {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: self-start;
                justify-content: space-evenly;
                font-family: $poppinsFont;

                span {
                    &:first-child {
                        color: $white;
                        font-size: 18px;
                    }

                    &:last-child {
                        color: $gray;
                        font-size: 16px;
                        font-family: $shabnamFont;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```